# c++ Bag Of Words Clustered Array Size Issue

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv

I'm trying to create a Bag Of Words program using `ORB` as my `detector` and `extractor` with `BruteForce` for the `matcher`.

Everything runs fine.

But my concern is that when I try to Cluster my Array of Descriptors, it shrinks from

`[32 x several thousand odd]`

to

`[32 x 1]`

I also don't really understand where 32 comes from either, the programs currently only reads in 14 images.

Code:

```
cout << " -- All Other Images Features Array Size: " << allImgFeaturesUnclustered.size();

BOWKMeansTrainer allImgBowTrainer(dictionarySize, termCrit, retries, flags);
Mat allImgDictionary = allImgBowTrainer.cluster(allImgFeaturesUnclustered);
BOWImgDescriptorExtractor allImgBowImgDesExtr(extractor,matcher);
allImgBowImgDesExtr.setVocabulary(allImgDictionary);

cout << " -- All Images Dictionary Size: " << allImgDictionary.size();
```

At the top line, when left to their full original size, the Array comes out as `[32 x 6969]` for all the Descriptors off all the images.

At the bottom line, after they have been Clustered, the Array comes out as `[32 x 1]`

I've done this is just one image and it still goes from `[32 x 458]` to `[32 x 1]`

Is this right? I've been pretty much teaching myself c++ and OpenCV for the past 2-3 weeks so my apologies if this is normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, it seems that 32 is both feature size of the `ORB` and the `dictionary size`. So if your feature size was 64 and dictionary size was 16, then you would see `[64 x 458]` to `[16 x 1]`.

Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562484/bag-of-visual-words-in-opencv/19564336#19564336).